# Why is my HTTP request URL not being generated for a Logic App?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-logic-apps

Good morning. I am new to logic apps and I am trying to figure out how I can trigger the execution based on a GET URL with three parameters. All the examples I've found on Google show the URL being generated once the JSON and relative path is entered, but that's not happening for me. Perhaps it's because I am creating the logic app in VS.

Here's what my "When a HTTP request is received" step looks like in the logic app.

[image]

I also tried removing the JSON and just using the parameters to pass the values to the function, as shown below. I'm just not sure the best way to do this.

[image]

All I really need to do is get the three parameters into the logic app so I can perform a function call with the parameters. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is my HTTP request URL not being generated for a Logic App?

You need to click `save`, and then the url will be automatically generated for the `When a HTTP request is received` trigger:

[image]

You can use this expression to [accept values through GET parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#accept-values-through-get-parameters):

```
triggerOutputs()['queries']['parameter-name']
```

For example:

[image]
[image]

Note：

**`Queries` need to pass parameters in the form of json.**

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the input. I was saving with no URL generated. I found that if I went to the portal in the sandbox environment I was able to have the URL generated, but the URL was not generated in Visual Studio. I also played with the parameters until I got them to work. Thanks again!